# Determine if this power series is convergent for Z on the boundary of it's disc of convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

So, this is the power series:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty$$(\frac{1+i\sqrt 3}{n^2})$$((\frac{z}{2})+i)^n$

I have already found the centre power series to be $C_n$= $-2i$

And the Radius of Convergence using the ratio test to be $R$=$1$

But I'm stuck with how to get the answer to seeing if the power series is convergent for z on the boundary of its disc of convergence.

I'm pretty sure you have to work out the modulus of the top function, but use $(z+2i)$ instead of $((\frac{z}{2})+i)^n$ as $C_n$=$-2i$ is the centre of the power series but I'm not sure how to solve for it. Could someone show me how to work this modulus out step-by-step please?

Comment: Why do you say the centre is $-2i$?  $z/2 + 1 = 0$ for $z = -2$.  Or was it supposed to be $(z/2)^2 + 1$?

Comment: Oh the $1$ in the bracket is supposed to be an $i$, wrote it wrong.

Comment: How you got the radius of convergence $R=1?$

Comment: After doing the ratio test it equalled: $(\frac{n}{n+1})^2$ and the function tends to infinity hence it equals 1

Comment: Rewrite series as $(1+i\sqrt{3})\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{n^2 2^n}(z+2i)^n}$ and denote $c_n=\dfrac{1}{n^2 2^n}.$ Then using the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) 
$R=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left| \dfrac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} \right|=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left| \dfrac{2^{n+1}(n+1)^2}{2^n n^2} \right|= 2 \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} {\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2}=2.$

Comment: Oh right, I checked the solutions for what my lecturer got and he got the same as me. I'm so confused right now. Thank you for showing me this!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Since the radius of convergence $R=2,$ then for each point on the boundary of disc of convergence we have $z+2i=2e^{i\varphi}.$ Thus for these points 
$$(1+i\sqrt{3})\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{1}{n^2 2^n}(z+2i)^n}=(1+i\sqrt{3})\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{2^n e^{in\varphi}}{n^2 2^n}}=(1+i\sqrt{3})\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{\dfrac{ e^{in\varphi}}{n^2}},$$  and the last series is absolutely convergent.